# regex to select digits after string

Tags: regex, text

i need a little help with some regex, im fairly new to it all however i feel like this may not be too complex for someone who isnt panicked by regex syntax :)

I have this block of text

```
{ "NewMessages": "0", "NewAlarms": "0", "Alarms": "13", "PartialAlarms": "", "AckAlarms": "1", "UnusualSens": "",
```

And need to select the values of each category, only the digit, so far i have selected the whole string with `("Alarms": )"*"\d{1,}"`however this obviously also selects Alarms and value, i need just the value of 15, however 15 will change frequently.

Any tips how to select any digits that far after "Alarms" ?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use a JSON library instead of parsing it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

you use the positive lookbehind:

```
(?<="Alarms": )"*"\d{1,}"
```

this should work for you
hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in group.

const regex_alarms = /("Alarms": )"*"(\d{1,})"/mg;

const regex_all = /"\w+": "([0-9]+)"/mg;

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
"Alarms": "(\d*)"
```

And your value will be in group 1. To get it:

```
$1
```